# Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04 broken by sudden restart of system

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04

I was upgrading my ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, by following the standard procedure using the terminal. I wrote the following commands.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

The second command downloaded the packages of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (download size was ~1.5GB). This was followed by the start of the install of the packages, when I used the chrome browser. The system underwent a sudden restart, and got stuck on a login loop, so I had to force restart it. Now I have broken packages of Ubuntu 20.04 on my system. Here is what I get by running

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bluetooth : Depends: blues
gnome-bluetooth : Depends: bluez (>= 5.5)
gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
indicator-bluetooth : Depends: bluez (>= 5)
libatk-adaptor:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installed
libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.41.1) but it is not installed
libatk1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.55.2) but it is not installed
libatspi2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installed
libcanberra-gtk0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installed
libgail-common:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
libgail18:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.27.3) but it is not installed
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.48.0) but it is not installed
libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.41.1) but it is not installed
libharfbuzz0b:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not installed
libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.41)
libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.41)
libpango-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installed
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: bluez (>= 5.23)
systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 237-3ubuntu10.41 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have tried running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again, but it's giving the same error, and asking me to run `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`. Also I have not got any Ubuntu 20.04 LTS features on my system yet, it's all as was before save this

[image: Ubuntu Version 20.04]

Also in the screenshot (as you can possibly observe) there is a (!) error on the top right corner, which is reads as follows :

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is a way to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't wish to just format the disk again and install a fresh copy of 20.04, but I might be forced to do so unless there is some other way out. Kindly, let me know.

Comment: try with sudo apt-get install -f and report back

Comment: I get the same error, as I have specified in the question. Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/wnT0SLq

Comment: can you try to choose another server in Software & Updates ? and then run again sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Comment: have you done an auto clean and tried to update after this?

Comment: I have tried an auto clean and autoremove

Comment: My software an updates were not opening, so I ran this command `sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/* `. sudo apt-get install -f seems to be working now.

Comment: Just an update: After successfully running, `sudo apt-get install -f`, the error on top right corner has vanished. But my `settings` is no longer working, and several of my applications have gone missing, including `software and updates`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing such issues in the future.

1. I used `sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to release all the held packages, followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`. Note in the second step, depending on which of your packages had unmet dependencies, it's possible that you might be deleting some of the very essential packages like settings and log in.
2. This is the most important step. Your system has now several packages that need to get installed (as you have cleared the row of broken packages). For this following 3 commands will do.

   > ```
   >  sudo apt-get update
   >  sudo apt-get upgrade 
   >  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   > ```

Following this, your computer might need a restart, and then everything should get fixed. Hope this helps someone!